# Clean up method for spring boot application after request process

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, httprequest, thread-local

How to implement a clean up method after request finish process in a spring boot application for clean data such as thread locals

I try with `ServletRequestListener.requestDestroyed` api, but it does not get hit after the request finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible answer is that you have neglected to register the listener.  The Servlet [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener.html) say:

> In order to receive these notification events, the implementation class must be either declared in the deployment descriptor of the web application, annotated with `WebListener`, or registered via one of the `addListener` methods defined on `ServletContext`.

There may be other ways to implement this using Spring; e.g. using a handler intercepter; see [Remove ThreadLocal object within a Spring MVC website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358426/remove-threadlocal-object-within-a-spring-mvc-website)

If you were using plain servlets (without the Spring MVC infrastructure), another approach would be to do the cleanup in your servlet's `service` method or the `doXxx` methods.  Or in a `Filter` in front of the servlet.

Comment: you are correct. i had to register it as a bean.. What is the best approach ServletRequestListener or HandlerInterceptorAdapter?  I think ServletRequestListener is simple. Also i found that all api's in HandlerInterceptorAdapter do the work after request finish in the controller know.

Comment: I don't have an opinion on that.